# Finding all pairs of sequences that differ at exactly one position

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need a data structure representing a set of sequences (all of the same, known, length) with the following non-standard operation:

> Find two sequences in the set that differ at exactly one index. (Or establish that no such pair exists.)

If `N` is the length of the sequences and `M` the number of sequences, there is an obvious `O(N*M*M)` algorithm. I wonder if there is a standard way of solving this more efficiently. I'm willing to apply pre-processing if needed.

Bonus points if instead of returning a pair, the algorithm returns *all* sequences that differ at the same point.

**Alternatively**, I am also interested in a solution where I can check efficiently whether a *particular* sequence differs at one index with from any sequence in the set. If it helps, we can assume that in the set, no two sequences have that property.

**Edit:** you can assume `N` to be reasonably small. By this, I mean improvements such as `O(log(N)*M*M)` are not immediately useful for my use case.

Comment: Can we assume the sequences contain integers?

Comment: @IVlad yes, if it helps. In my case, I happen to have a perfect hash function at my disposal (for elements, not for sequences)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each sequence and each position i in that sequence, calculate a hash of the sequence without position i and add it to a hash table. If there is already an entry in the table, you have found a potential pair that differs only in one position. Using [rolling hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) from both start and end and combining them, you can calculate each hash in constant time. The total running time is expected O(N*M).

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to suggest. You could additionally hash the entire sequence as well. So each sequence S(n), would have N partial hashes hS(i), and one complete hash hS. Then enter into a single hash table the combined hashes ((hS)|(hS(i)) << hashSize ). For any test sequence compute N hashes in the same way, and look each one up in the same single hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Select j sets of k indexes each randomly (make sure none of the sets overlap).

For each set XOR the elements.

You now have j fingerprints for each document.

Compare sequences based on these fingerprints. j-1 fingerprints should match if the sequences do indeed match. But the converse might not be true and you might have to check location by location.

More clarification on comparison part: Sort all fingerprints from all documents (or use hash table). In that way you don't have to compare every pair, but only the pairs that do have a matching fingerprint.

Comment: If my `j` sets all contain the index where sequences differ, then none of the fingerprints will match, it seems?

Comment: @Philippe Yes. I forgot to add that sets should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: OK, that can (statistically) improve on `N` in `O(N*M*M)`... For very long sequences, that definitely sounds like a good approach. I was hoping to improve on the quadratic factor, though. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: @Philippe You dont have to do O(N*M*M). You can sort the fingerprints and process more efficiently. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive approach:

- Find all sets of sequences that have the same first half through sort or hash.
- For each of these sets, repeat the whole process now only looking at the second half.
- Find all sets of sequences that have the same second half through sort or hash.
- For each of these sets, repeat the whole process now only looking at the first half.
- When you've reached length 1, all those that don't match are what you're looking for.

Pseudo-code:

```
findPairs(1, N)

findPairs(set, start, end)
  mid = (start + end)/2
  sort set according to start and mid indices
  if end - start == 1
    last = ''
    for each seq: set
      if last != '' and seq != last
        DONE - PAIR FOUND
      last = seq
  else
    newSet = {}
    last = ''
    for each seq: set
      if newSet.length > 1 and seq and last don't match from start to mid indices
        findPairs(newSet, mid, end)
        newSet = {}
      newSet += seq
      last = seq
```

It should be easy enough to modify the code to be able to find all pairs.

**Complexity?** I may be wrong but:

The max depth is `log M`. (I believe) the worst case would be if all sequences are identical. In this case the work done will be `O(N*M*log M*log M)`, which is better than `O(N*M*M)`.